# O que fazer para este código funcionar no celular

Tags: jquery, mobile

Peguei esse código pronto para montar um menu falso off-canvas, ele está funcionando perfeitamente, mas quando vou acessar pelo celular o menu não aparece, o que eu preciso fazer?

```
$(".toggle-canvas").click(function () {
$("#menu-canvas").toggleClass('menu-canvas-active');
    removeClass = false;
});

$("#menu-canvas").click(function() {
    removeClass = false;
});
$("html").click(function () {
    if (removeClass) {
        $("#menu-canvas").removeClass('menu-canvas-active');
    }
    removeClass = true;
})
```

Outra pergunta, o addClass funciona em celular?

Comment: Tem certeza que a parte que dá problema é a parte de código que colocou? Acho muito mais provável ser algo de CSS que o navegador mobile não suporte e acabe não renderizando o menu. Pode fazer um exemplo mínimo que reproduza o problema? (completo, com html, css e js)

Comment: Já experimentaste com `$(document)` em vez de `$("html")`?

Comment: Em resposta ao `addClass`, qualquer método de jQuery funciona em qualquer dispositivo, incluindo smartPhones.

Comment: Será que não deveria adicionar de `touchend` junto ao `click`?

Comment: Poderia informar se a minha resposta ajudou? Ou se não, qual o problema que houve?

Answer (score 1):

Primeiramente, sua variável `removeClass` não está definida, isto pode acabar misturando com variaveis de um level superior ou globais, portanto sempre use `var ...`

Ou coisa, evite criar os eventos no "primeiro level" do javascript (seria o level global), algo como:

```
<script>
var oi = 1;
</script>
```

Prefira algo como:

```
<script>
(function () {
    var oi = 1;
}());
</script>
```

Assim você pode evitar misturar as variáveis

Dando seguimento com isto algo que você poderia fazer seria usar o evento `.on` do Jquery ao invés de `.click` (equivalente ao `.bind("click",`)

Os eventos `.on` verificam modificações no `DOM`, se for adicionado um objeto novo ele automaticamente aplica o evento. Digo isto pois, pois acredito que o você esteja tentando adicionar o evento `.click`, quando o objeto ainda não foi renderizado.

Um exemplo de `.on` seria:

`$(document).on("click", "SELETOR", function ()  { console.log("Test..."); });`

No seu caso, o seu script poderia trabalhar assim:

```
(function () { //"Isola" as variáveis 
    var removeClass = false;//Define a variável

    //Configura o click para o elemento .toggle-canvas, assim que este "existir"
    $(document).on("click", ".toggle-canvas", function () {
        $("#menu-canvas").toggleClass('menu-canvas-active');
        removeClass = false;
    });

    //Configura o click para o elemento #menu-canvas, assim que este "existir"
    $(document).on("click", "#menu-canvas", function() {
        removeClass = false;
    });

    //Não é necessário .on aqui, pois o document é um dos primeiros elementos "dentro do javascript" a existirem
    $(document).click(function () {
        if (removeClass) {
            $("#menu-canvas").removeClass("menu-canvas-active");
        }

        removeClass = true;
    });
}());
```